# Golang html templates index

Tags: html, go

When I range over a slice with {{range}} I can instantiate many elements each with data pipeline. But I cannot see how to find the index of each element in the range. With go we can:

```
for i, _ := range x {}
```

can we do something similar with templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my example. Wish it help you

```
 {{ range $index,$article := $articles }}

    <a href="/articles/{{ $article.Id }}" class="list-group-item">
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ $index }}</p>  // index here start with 0
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ $article.Title }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ $article.Body }}</p>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ .FormatDate $article.CreatedOn }}</p>

    </a>
  {{ end }}
```

Comment: interesting, trouble is with multiple values. I try $val.FIELD

Comment: i dont understand your mean. In my example, $articles is a list of article. and {{$article.Title}} print the value of "Title" field..

Answer (score 1):

I guess following will work

```
{{ range $key, $val := . }}
<strong>{{ $key }}</strong>: {{ $val }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: interesting, trouble is with multiple values. I try $val.FIELD